# Android Notification BigPictureStyle picture getting cropped from sides on small devices

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have created a notification with Big Picture Style. I have sizes for mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi. On tablets the picture looks great, but on phone (Moto X), the picture is getting cropped from the left and right side.

What should be done so that the full picture is seen ??

Answer (score 1):

Here's a document from google I think might be helpful:[What's new in Android](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/io2012/presentations/live%20to%20website/105.pdf)

On page 52, it said

> Images should be ≤ 450dp wide, ~2:1 aspect

By the way, the height of notification big picture should be no bigger than 256dp.

Hope this will help you.